How to write the Python Program for the following condition?
How to write a Python Program for the following condition:

Let me explain how I tried to write the code.
$a=$ int$($input$($'enter the first integer between $1$ and $9$'$))$
$b=$ int$($input$($'enter the second integer between $0$ and $9$'$))$
$c=$ int$($input$($'enter the third integer between $0$ and $9$'$))$
if$(a+b^{2}+c^{3}==100(a)+10(b)+c):$

print$(abc)$

else:

print$($ "the code is wrong"$)$

But I don't think that my code is correct.
I want a python code which will automatically fetch the numbers after it is executed.
Please help me out. I am really in trouble with this problem.
Wishes
Mathematics

Programming questions are off-topic here. Also don't use images to state your problem.

Then can you kindly inform me about the programming questions site ? Actually I really want to know the code to this question

Check on https://stackoverflow.com/

$\text{You don’t have to read user input, you have to find such values, it’s simply 3 nested for loops:}$
$\begin{aligned}
&\text{for } a \text{ in range}(1, 10): \\
&\quad \text{for } b \text{ in range}(0, 10): \\
&\quad\quad \text{for } c \text{ in range}(0, 10): \\
&\quad\quad\quad \text{if } a + b^2 + c^3 == 100*a + 10*b + c: \\
&\quad\quad\quad\quad \text{print}(\text{f}"a \text{ is: } \{a\}, b \text{ is: } \{b\}, c \text{ is: } \{c\}")
\end{aligned}$

even though that question is related to tags that you used, it's more suitable to post such a question on stackoverflow, instead of CS, because it's simply a coding question not a problem-solving related one.

Thank you Friend very much. God Bless You
